# Android App to show ASP.NET Website

Tags: android, asp.net

I have a question on good practise. I have a website where people can do some stuff after they logged in. I want to make an app, which gives mobile users the opportunity to instead of opening the web site, they can just open the app. Because you need to log in, I was thinking about using `WebView` and display the site, because I do not see any necessary to learn Android code using this way. Is it considered good practise to use an Android app this way?

Comment: Why don't you load the url of your website into the WebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead making hybrid web application you can create [PWA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_Web_Apps):

> Progressive Web Apps (PWAs) are web applications that are regular web
>   pages or websites, but can appear to the user like traditional
>   applications or native mobile applications. The application type
>   attempts to combine features offered by most modern browsers with the
>   benefits of a mobile experience.

See tutorial: [Building Progressive Web apps with ASP.NET Core](https://dotnetthoughts.net/progressive-web-apps-on-aspnet-core/).

See also [tutorial from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web service in server side and use traditional android interface (e.g. two EditText for username and password, one button for login and one TextView for errors)

Comment: You misunderstood something, the website has its login form. I am just bypassing "the opening a browser on the phone" with the app. Basically its just a browser for my website.

Comment: OK if you just need a login you can use two edit boxes and one button in a traditional android interface and use a web service in your server